# C++ variable reset to 0 after calling x64 assembly function

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm trying to call x64 assembly function from C++ code with four parameters and the assembly function reset the first parameter to zero every time. Please find the code snippet below.

**C++ code: test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int IntegerShift_(unsigned int a, unsigned int* a_shl, unsigned int* a_shr, unsigned int count);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    unsigned int a = 3119, count = 6, a_shl, a_shr;
    std::cout << "a value before calling " << a << std::endl;
    IntegerShift_(a, &a_shl, &a_shr, count);
    std::cout << "a value after calling " << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**x64 assembly code: test.asm**

```
section .data
section .bss
section .text

global IntegerShift_
    IntegerShift_:
        ;prologue
        push rbp
        mov rbp, rsp

        mov rax, rdi
        shl rax, cl
        mov [rsi], rax
        mov rax, rdi
        shr rax, cl
        mov [rdx], rax
        xor rax,rax

        ;epilogue
        mov rbp, rsp
        pop rbp
        ret
```

I'm working on the below environment.

> *OS* - Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
>   *Assembler* - nasm (2.13.02)
>   *C++ compiler* - g++ (7.4.0)
>   *processor* - Intel® Pentium(R) CPU G3240 @ 3.10GHz × 2

and I'm compiling my code as below

```
$ nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf test.asm
$ g++ -g -o test test.cpp test.o
$ ./test
$ a value before calling 3119
$ a value after calling 0
```

But if i comment out the line `mov [rdx], rax` from assembly function, its not resetting the value of `variable a`. I'm new to x64 assembly programming and I couldn't find the relation between rdx register and variable a.

Comment: That does not make much sense. The `a` is passed by value. Try making it `const` to see what happens.

Comment: @Resurrection making `a` as constant resolved the issue, but could you please explain the reason for that? how do i change the value of `a` to another value and call the assembly function again.

Comment: @Resurrection's suggestion to make `a` a constant merely lets the compiler use it as an immediate for the call to `cout.operator<<(int)`, instead of storing/reloading it to the stack where your buggy asm can destroy it.  It's not a fix for the asm bug, and just has the obvious effect.  (Obvious if you know how compilers work in anti-optimized debug mode :P)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unsigned int* a_shl, unsigned int* a_shr` are pointers to `unsigned int`, a 32-bit (dword) type.

**You do two qword stores, `mov [rsi], rax` and `mov [rdx], rax` which store outside of the pointed-to objects.**

The C equivalent would be a function that takes `unsigned int*` args and does
`*(unsigned long)a_shr = a>>count;`.  This is of course UB, and behaviour like this (overwriting other variables) is pretty much what you'd expect.

---

Presumably you compiled with optimization disabled so the caller actually reloaded `a` from the stack.  And it put `a_shr` or `a_shl` next to `a` in its stack frame, **and one of your stores zeroed your caller's copy of `a`.**

(As usual, gcc happened to zero the upper 32 bits of RDI while it put `a` into EDI as the first arg.  Writing a 32-bit register zero-extends to the full register.  So your other bug; right shifting high garbage into the low 32 bits for `a_shr`, didn't bite you with this caller.)

Simpler implementation:

```
global IntegerShift    ; why the trailing underscore?  That's weird for no reason.
    IntegerShift:
        ;prologue not needed, we don't even use the stack
        ; so don't waste instructions making a frame pointer.

        mov   eax, edi
        shl   rax, cl              ; a<<count
        mov   [rsi], eax           ; 32-bit store

        ;mov rax, rdi       ; we can just destroy our local a, we're done with it
        shr    edi, cl             ; a>>count
        mov   [rdx], edi           ; 32-bit store

        xor   eax, eax             ; return 0
        ret
```

`xor eax, eax` is the most efficient way to zero a 64-bit register (no wasted REX prefix).  And your return value is only 32-bit anyway because you declared it `int`, so it makes no sense to be using 64-bit registers.

BTW, if you had BMI2 available (which you don't on your budget Pentium CPU, unfortunately), you could avoid all the register copying, and be more efficient on Intel CPUs (SHL/RX is only 1 uop instead of 3 for `shl/r reg, cl` because of legacy x86 FLAGS-unmodified semantics for the cl=0 case)

```
    shlx   eax, edi, ecx
    shrx   edi, edi, ecx
    mov   [rsi], eax
    mov   [rdx], edi
    xor   eax, eax
    ret
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you please tell why the variable `a` doesn't reset to 0 if I make it as const ?

Comment: @Vencat: I just replied to @ Resurrection's odd comment under your question.  It changes how GCC compiles the caller so the bug happens not to step on anything that you notice.